# Git submodules : must a file located in a submodule's folder be tracked by that same submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-add

I have git repo A containing submodule B. Some file *file.c* is located inside B's folder, itself inside of A's folder as you'd expect. Question : can I track this file *file.c* from A and not from B ? Does that even make any sense ?

Idea is that any user of B has to add their own *file.c* in this specific location of B's folder hierarchy. If someone fails to do that but still adds B as submodule, B will simply mention that there is no target file upon compiling/running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have git repo A containing submodule B.

In other words, you might have:

```
$ cd /path/to/A
$ ls
B/    README
```

for (slightly silly) example.  (There's also a `.gitmodules` here but it is hidden away since it is a dot-file.)

> A file `file.c` is located inside B's folder, itself inside of A's folder as you'd expect.  Question: can I track this file from A and not from B?  Does that even make any sense?

The *question* makes sense, but the *answer* is a resounding **No** (*boom, thud*).  The problem is the way the existence of submodule B is represented within repository A.

The current (HEAD) commit of repository A has a `tree` object that claims the existence of at least two `blob` objects:

- `.gitmodules`: this file has in it the URL for a repository, along with a `path` entry that says `B`
- `B`: this blob has mode `160000` (a "gitlink" entry).  The "contents" of this blob are the commit hash ID that Git should check out, once Git has cloned the URL so that `B/` exists.  Presumably, checking out that hash ID gets you a file named `file.c`, so that `B/file.c` exists.

To store the existence of a blob that would be extracted into `B/file.c` within the superproject `A`, Git would need to store a second `tree` object named `B` in the top level tree (this second `tree` object would itself have a blob named `file.c`, which would then be extracted into `B/file.c`).  But there is already a gitlink `blob` object named `B`, so it can't: a duplicate name is disallowed.

> Idea is that any user of B has to add their own file.c in this specific location of B's folder hierarchy. If someone fails to do that but still adds B as submodule, B will simply mention that there is no target file upon compiling/running.

What you could do is store, in submodule repository B, a *symlink* named `file.c`, pointing to `../user-supplied-file.c` or `../user/file.c` or some such.  Now repository A needs to contain `user-supplied-file.c` or `user/file.c` or whatever the link points to.

Note that this couples the submodule rather tightly with the superproject.  At this point, it might be more reasonable not to bother with a submodule at all.  Libraries and other such submodule-worthy items do not typically require additional *source code*; they might have routines that take *function pointers*, and call those functions through those pointers, but they don't have entirely-external source dependencies.